# Can't reinstall Adobe Reader XI

Tags: adobe-reader

I encountered an error when trying to use Adobe Reader online, getting an error that stated that Adobe Reader was running and I should close it before trying to use it here.  I did that, plus rebooted the computer and still got the error.  I called the site support and they said I should uninstall Adobe Reader and then go online to install it again.  I tried this and now it will not install "Error 1303:  Installer has insufficient privileges to access this directory "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader11.0\Reader.  Log in as Admin".  I was logged in as Admin at the time.  So then I decided to remove the entire Adobe file folder and got an error of "Need permission from SYSTEM to make changes.  I am now stuck without Adobe.  Adobe did not give me an option of putting Adobe Reader in another folder.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Please edit your answer to indicate what OS you're running.  Also, can you clarify what you mean by "trying to use Adobe Reader online"? Do you mean you're trying to view a PDF document _within_ your browser, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a Java problem once by updating Java. I had java in my system but applications didn't  want recognize it and said I had none. I tried re-installing but it didn't work. I updated my Java from 8.### to a higher version through the control panel. I believe I disabled it to auto-update. Even if the official site wanted me to install Java 7, my Java worked afterwards.

You could try making an update to Adobe Reader so Registry keys would be rewritten along with some other things.

A clean un-install and re-install should work too.

Answer (score 0):

When you said YOU SHOULD LOG IN AS ADMIN what do mean actually?You logged into your adobe account or You are logged into your system as a guest rather than admin? 
Because If you have logged into your system profile as administrator then you have authority on each and every software you had installed but a guest doesn't have that many privileges.

And Removing adobe folder will not be the solution to your problem.You have to uninstall it.Because uninstallation also deletes registry files buy merely deleting adobe folder isn't the right method.

I recommend you to install Revo Uninstaller for such problems which deletes the leftover temp files and you can freshly install again.